# makefile: concatenate text with infix operator

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is there a simple function in GNU make to concatenate text and put an "operator" between single parts? I mean, the operator token must occurr n-1 times, only between two tokens.
Example: I have a variable with a list of paths to exclude from compilation:

```
EXCLUDE_PATH = $(BASE_DIR)/aaa* $(BASE_DIR)/bbb*
```

Later I want to use that variable to generate an exclusion rule for `find` command, like:

```
-not \( -path '$(BASE_DIR)/aaa*' -o -path '$(BASE_DIR)/bbb*' \)
```

Notice the `-o` between them.
A first try:

```
FIND_EXCL_LIST = $(EXCLUDE_PATH:%=-path '%' -o)
FIND_EXCL_RULE = -not \( $(FIND_EXCL_LIST) \)
```

But this leaves an extra `-o` at the end, resulting in an error.

Currently I resorted to add a `-false` at the end, as a stub OR parameter.

Provided that I prefer to decouple variable definitions from their specific uses, is there possibly a simpler way to do that with predefined functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Louis is correct: there's no magical way of doing this.  But if, instead of trying to remove the last item or treat it specially, you instead treat the first item specially, the work is much simpler to understand (I think); you can create a function `combine` that takes two arguments: the first is the text to put between the words and the second is a space-separated list of words to combine:

```
combine = $(word 1,$2) $(foreach W,$(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2),$1 $W)
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
$(call combine,-o,$(EXCLUDE_LIST))
```

to get output like:

```
$(BASE_DIR)/aaa* -o $(BASE_DIR)/bbb*
```

Comment: Thanks to both, I never considered you can do such complicated tasks with the various text functions and "call". I'm choosing this answer because the "combine" function fits exactly and can be reused in many cases.

Comment: What happened to the other answer??

Comment: "deleted by owner 4 hours ago".  I guess Louis didn't want to leave it up.

Comment: Here's a `commafy` function, in case someone finds this post looking for that. Because `$(wordlist ...)` wants to space-separate anything you give it, you need a slightly different approach to get the commas stuck in the right places: `commafy = $(foreach W,$(filter-out $(lastword $1),$1),$W,) $(lastword $1)`